# Why do "bookmark" and "follow" behave differently for logged-out users when both are non-privileged features?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, user-experience, follow-post, anonymous-visitors

When a user is logged out, there are some elements that they can interact with:

> [image]

And this is how they behave:

- Upvote/downvote: show a "join the community" pop-up with the required reputation.
- Bookmark (only on the question): **show a tooltip**, informing the user to log in or register.

  > [image]
- Timeline: the same as logged-in users.
- Share link: the same as logged-in users.
- "Improve this question/answer" link: the same as users without full edit privilege, except without "you are not logged in" text.
- Follow: **show a "join the community" pop-up**.

  > [image]

Personally, I would expect the "follow" link to behave like the "bookmark" button since both do not require any reputation. Though, whether the tooltip or the pop-up is more preferred, can we have it more consistent?

Comment: It looks like this has since been made more consistent. I opened an incognito window and tried bookmarking this question and the link caused the pop-up to open instead of the tooltip.